# Settings file types converting

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, indexer

I would like to save the user radio- button preference in the `Settings` file.

Therefore, I have created a setting property called `radioButtonIsChecked` boolean typed.

```
radioButton.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default[radioButton.Name + "IsChecked"];
```

When I try the code above I get an error that object cannot be converted to bool.
I understand the reason is that the returned value from Settings.Default indexer is object.

Is there a way to refer the settings- property type when retrieved from by-name-indexer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the retrieved value will *be* of the right type, just cast it:

```
radioButton.Checked = (bool) Properties.Settings.Default[radioButton.Name + "IsChecked"];
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it a little dangerous to convert this way? Is `Convert.ToBoolean` better?

Comment: @user3165438: What do you mean by "dangerous"? If it's not a `bool`, that presumably means you've got a bug, right? In which case an exception is a perfectly fine result. What situation are you concerned about, and what outcome do you think is better than what the cast does for you?

Comment: You are right about the conversion; just wanted to ask what's the best way to do it.